# Not able to call mint() on contract using Ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, nft

I am trying to call mint() on a ERC721 contract which accepts two parameters: _address & tokenURI. I have the following code which I am calling from frontend:

```
const mintNFT = async (tokenURI)=>{
  state.isMinting=true;
  const contractAddress = import.meta.env.VITE_SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress,contractABI.abi,snap.signer);
  debugger;
  try {
    const mint = await contract.mint(snap.walletAddress,tokenURI);
    await mint.wait();
    console.log("minted successfully!! ");
    state.isMinting=false;
    state.isMinted=true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while minting! ",error);
    state.isMinting=false;
  }
}
```

But I am getting error when contract.mint() is called. I am getting this error,
`Cannot assign to read only property '_events' of object '#<Web3Provider>`

Currently I am using ethers.js v^5.7.2
I am also getting this warning in metamask:

```
We noticed that the current website tried to use the removed window.web3 API. If the site appears to be broken, please click here for more information.
```

I researched a lot on the internet but was not able to find the solution of this problem. May anyone else also encountered the same problem?

Deployed Smart contract (verified): https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1604Fef32d056bB14035056A12d78EBd9706680E

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with the `Web3Provider` object of `ethers.js`.

FIrst we check if `Web3Provider` is initialized properly

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```

Then we get the signer and use it for our contract

```
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI.abi, signer);
```

then in our mint function:

```
const mintNFT = async (tokenURI) => {
  state.isMinting = true;
  
  const contractAddress = import.meta.env.VITE_SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI.abi, signer);
  
  try {
    const mint = await contract.mint(snap.walletAddress, tokenURI);
    await mint.wait();
    console.log("minted successfully!! ");
    state.isMinting = false;
    state.isMinted = true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while minting! ", error);
    state.isMinting = false;
  }
}
```